# Android NFC application security testing

Tags: android, security, nfc

How can I go about doing security testing of an Android NFC application? Is there is any tool or methodology that can be used to do security testing of an Android NFC application which does communication in P2P mode or Card Emulation mode?

Comment: what kind of security testing?

Comment: I think it was called "your brain, a sniffer and a good scripting language"

Answer (score 0):

Specialized tools to emulate P2P or tag communication exist, but these are generally extremely expensive. But before you go that route, it makes sense to consider against what kind of security threats you want to protect your NFC app. Android takes care of all the low-level NFC communication, so your app does not need to worry about that. Also parsing of NDEF data is done by the Android system. So I would say most things are taken care of for your app by the Android system and your app does not need to worry about it.

Comment: I believe Android by default does not provide protection against the known NFC security vulnerabilities such as, Data Modification/Insertion, Eavesdropping, Relay Attacks etc. So is there is any way one can test Android NFC application against such attacks?

Comment: OK, I would call that application level security. That is not really specific for NFC, I think, in the sense that NFC is probably not much more or less vulnerable to these attacks than other wireless technologies. One should not rely on the security of the communication link for application security. My interpretation of your question was about potential software problems resulting from the software stack related to NFC: malformed messages, buffer overflows, that sort of thing. Android with its Java environment provides quite good protection against that out of the box, I would say.

Comment: In P2P mode, all an Android app can do is receive NDEF messages and send a single NDEF message per connection. So an elaborate authentication protocol between phones over NFC is probably not possible. One can encrypt and/or MAC the payload of all NDEF messages. Relay detection seems unlikely to me, because of the limited message exchange.

Comment: Card emulation takes place outside of the control of the applications, it is handled by the hardware. The security of that comes down to the security of the embedded Secure Element (which is Common Criteria certified in the case of Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication#Security_aspects

In relation to your comment on NFC Guy's post no Android doesn't for the most part, you're expected to deal with most of it yourself:

- Eavesdropping is possible on an NFC connection, there's no encryption provided, if you want to keep information sent across an NFC connection secure then do some encryption at the application level. Devices such as the Proxmark3 can eavesdrop NFC communications: http://proxmark3.com/
- Data modification is possible but it depends on the encoding of link... See the Wikipedia page for more about this, I don't have much knowledge at this level.
- Relay attacks are possible on NFC connections, papers such as this one: http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/618.pdf show a practical implementation of them being carried out, just using a BlackBerry and a Nokia phone. You can try and detect them using distance bounding protocols or location based protocols although are somewhat inexact.